# Is This A lua Variable Scope Issue (and how can it be solved)?

Tags: lua

**A very strange error, showing an object is nil.**

the code in subject is

```
while pbs:HasNext() do
    local char = self.DecodeCharacter(pbs)
    ...
```

One would think, that if `pbs:HasNext()` is `true`, it means that, `pbs` is **not** `nil`, whatsoever.

However, the print(pbs) - the first line of `HTMLEntityCodec:DecodeCharacter` prints `nil`

```
function HTMLEntityCodec:DecodeCharacter(pbs)
    print(pbs)
    ...
```

The entire file dumped below, it was stripped from 1800+ lines to 110 so it can be clear for SO users to get he context. But that stripping took away all logic from the code, so do not get confused by that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

function Inherits( baseClass )
    local new_class = {}
    local class_mt = { __index = new_class }

    function new_class:create()
        local newinst = {}
        setmetatable( newinst, class_mt )
        return newinst
    end

    if baseClass then
        setmetatable( new_class, { __index = baseClass } )
    end

    return new_class
end


-------------------------------------------
-- PushbackString
-------------------------------------------
PushbackString = Inherits({})

function PushbackString:Init(input)
    self.input = input
    self.pushback = nil
    self.temp = nil
    self.index = 0 
    self.mark = 0
end

-- Mark the current index, so the client can reset() to it if need be.        
function PushbackString:HasNext()
    return true
end

function PushbackString:Mark ()
    self.temp = self.pushback
    self.mark = self.index
end


BaseCodec = Inherits({}) 

function BaseCodec:Decode(input)
    local buff = ''    
    local pbs = PushbackString:create()

    pbs:Init(input)

    while pbs:HasNext() do
        local char = self.DecodeCharacter(pbs)
        if char ~= nil then
            buff = buff .. char
        else
            buff = buff .. pbs:Next()
        end
    end
    return buff
end


HTMLEntityCodec = Inherits(BaseCodec)
-- HTMLEntityCodec.classname = ('HTMLEntityCodec')

function HTMLEntityCodec:DecodeCharacter(pbs)
    print(pbs)
    pbs:Mark()    
end

DefaultEncoder = Inherits({})

function DefaultEncoder:Init(codecs)
    self.html_codec = HTMLEntityCodec:create()
end

function DefaultEncoder:TestInput(input , strict)
    print ("\n----------------8<----------------8<----------------\n")
    print ("Input:\t" .. input)
    -- default value
    if strict == nil then strict = true end

    -- nothing to do
    if input == nil then return nil end

    local working = input
    local codecs_found = {}
    local found_count = 0
    local clean = false

    while not clean do
        clean = true
        old = working
        working = self.html_codec:Decode( working )
        if old ~= working then
            print ("Warning:\tINTRUSION DETECTED")
        end
    end

    print ("Output:\t".. working)
    return working
end


local default_encoder = DefaultEncoder:create()
default_encoder:Init()
default_encoder:TestInput("%25", true)

----------8<-----------8<--------------8<----------------
```

END OF FILE

Console Output:

```
tzury@1005:~/devel/lua$ lua problem.lua 

----------------8<----------------8<----------------

Input:  %25
nil
lua: problem.lua:70: attempt to index local 'pbs' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        problem.lua:70: in function 'DecodeCharacter'
        problem.lua:54: in function 'Decode'
        problem.lua:96: in function 'TestInput'
        problem.lua:109: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Comment: Your 'codec' variable is global - is this by design? If not, try changing it to local variable like so: `local codec = DefaultCodec:create()` and also `local char = self.Decode(codec)`.

Comment: @MichalKottman, it was local, but I changed to global owe to the issue I faced, which did not solve the problem. This is quite strange since `codec:HasNext()` means codec is no nil, why do `self.Decode` gets `codec` as nil? the first line of `self.decode` is `print...` which shows it is `nil`

Comment: You do not show the implementation of `DefaultCodec`, so it's hard to guess what actually happens. I guess you call this in a single-threaded, no coroutine way, so the only place where `codec` may be modified is in `DefaultCodec` itself.

Comment: @MichalKottman I just stripped down the code from 1800+ lines to 110 which is the minimal subset and the problem still exists. Code may not make any logical sense, but ignore that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the crash happens on this line:

```
local char = self.DecodeCharacter(pbs)
```

The problem is that you are calling `DecodeCharacter` with incorrect number of arguments.

**Solution**: call it like this (notice the colon):

```
local char = self:DecodeCharacter(pbs)
```

**Explanation**:

When you define functions in Lua using the colon (`:`), you are using a syntax sugar which hides an implicit first argument named `self`. Definitions like:

```
function HTMLEntityCodec:DecodeCharacter(pbs) ... end
```

Are actually 'translated' to this:

```
HTMLEntityCodec.DecodeCharacter = function (self, pbs) ... end
```

When you call the function, you either need to pass the `self` argument yourself, or use the colon call to supply it automatically. In your code (`self.DecodeCharacter(pbs)`), you are passing `pbs` which ends up as `self` in `HTMLEntityCodec.DecodeCharacter`, and `pbs` ends up being `nil`. Both following calls are equivalent and should solve the issue:

```
local char = self.DecodeCharacter(self, pbs)
local char = self:DecodeCharacter(pbs)
```